# Getting all the content of table and append it using ajax with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a simple sample on how to insert using AJAX and retrieving it then append it in a `<div>` after getting it. But I am having trouble on getting all the content of the table, it's returning a null values.

```
<div id="wrap-body">
  <form action method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
  <div id="info">
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#submit').click(function (){
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var msg = $('#msg').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'get.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:'username='+username+'&msg='+msg,
                success: function (data){
                    $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data.username+"</p> <p> your message  is:"+data.mesg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
$host='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='12345';
$db = 'feeds';

$connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cant connect");
mysql_select_db($db) or die("cant select the".$db);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO info(user_name,message) VALUES('$username','$msg')";

if(@!mysql_query($insert)){
    die('error insertion'.mysql_error());
}

$get = "SELECT * FROM info ";

$result=mysql_query($get)or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $return  = $row['user_name'];
    $return = $row['message'];
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: Any errors happening or what is your exact issue?

Comment: Did u try to alert data.username and see if you are getting data properly ?

Comment: there is no errors but, im not returning all the data inside the table and appending it to a div using ajax

Comment: quick comment: try not to do this `id="submit"`. call it something else.

Comment: $return  = $row['user_name'];     
$return = $row['message']; you are overwriting $return .

Comment: i try to alert it and it returns undefined

Comment: `type: 'POST'`, `url: 'get.php'`. ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while should **create array and then do json_encode**

Try below code

```
$data=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$data[] = array(
   'username'=>$row['user_name'],
   'mesg'=>$row['message']
);
}

echo json_encode($data);
exit
```

Now write your javascript success handler as below

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'get.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:'username='+username+'&msg='+msg,
                success: function (data){
                   $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                     $('#info').append("<p> you are:"+data[i].username+"</p> <p> your message  is:"+data[i].mesg);
                   });​

                }
            });
```

Comment: was about to write the same thing :P

Comment: what is the point in overwriting $data with every row from the query?

Comment: check my updated answer for fetch all data and append them all in the div

Comment: GDB i tried your update but i keep on having }); illegal character after the $.each(); on my console. du u have any idea why? here it is http://pastebin.com/xe04PwUd

Comment: It is BOM side effect means you have some ascii character in your file.I just copied your pastebin code and cleaned it. Then, everything works fine. So open your file into Notepad++ editor, then you can see '?' after }); of $.each(). just remove that character and save your file into Notepad++.Then run your file into browser and you will not get this error again

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues you have to fix, but you have to start with returning the same type as expected by the ajax call:

```
$return = array()
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $return['username']  = $row['user_name'];     
  $return['mesg'] = $row['message'];

}

echo json_encode($return);
```